# How to create a select - option in Zend Framework +MySQL Table

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-db-table

How to create a select - option in Zend Framework +MySQL Table

COntroller:

```
$persons = new Application_Model_DbTable_Persons();
$data_persons = $persons->findPersons();
```

Controller and View? How to? o.O

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
   $this->view->dataPerson = $data_persons;
```

View Html.

```
  foreach($this->dataPerson as $datPers):
               //Example Get person name.
          echo $this->escape($datPers->name);
           and etc.

 endforeach;
```

Comment: =(

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/namsohj/Dropbox/Proyecto de Grado/Desarrollo/Asuntos_Estudiantiles/application/views/scripts/beneficiarios/insertar.phtml on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/namsohj/Dropbox/Proyecto de Grado/Desarrollo/Asuntos_Estudiantiles/application/views/scripts/beneficiarios/insertar.phtml on line 6

You can help me with remote acces?

Comment: Go through this Example so that you can understand what you are doing. It exactly explains what you need to do.    http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

Comment: The example not include "select" combobox

Answer (score 0):

The options to the Select box can be added as an array using `addMultiOptions()` function

```
$persons = new Application_Model_DbTable_Persons();
$data_persons = $persons->findPersons();
$data_persons_array = array();

foreach($this->dataPerson as $datPers)
    $data_persons_array[$datPers->id] =  $datPers->name


$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('name')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
        ->addMultiOptions($data_persons_array); //Will add the options to select box
```

Comment: All this is in the controller? and the line ($name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');) print error, I must include a library?

Comment: It should be added to the php file where you are creating the form and form elements. If you are following the `Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf` by Akrabat... you can put it in `forms/Album.php`